# Set autocomplete input field display value different from actual value

Tags: javascript, forms, autocomplete

I have a text field in my form which is filled using this [autocomplete script](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp). When a value is selected from the autocomplete suggestions, I want the field to be filled with the displayed value from the suggestions, (stored in array `arr`), but I want a different value to be submitted along with the POST request when the form is submitted (stored in array `arr2`).

The code:

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value = '" + arr[i] + "'>";
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    closeAllLists();
});
a.appendChild(b);
```

`arr` array contains the values that should be displayed, while another array `arr2` contains the actual values that should be passed during the POST request.

What I have tried already:

1) I tried using the data-value property to hold the actual values and tried to set it as `inp.value` but in that case when I click a suggestion, it does not get autofilled.

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' data-value = '" + arr2[i] + "' value = '" + arr[i] + "'>";
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].data-value;
    closeAllLists();
});
a.appendChild(b);
```

2) I tried setting the value property directly to the values from `arr2` but then on clicking a suggestion, the input field gets filled with the value that has to be passed, and not the one that has to be displayed. Code below:

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value = '" + arr2[i] + "'>";
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    closeAllLists();
});
a.appendChild(b);
```

Comment: why not use hidden fields which will contain data to be send to server, you can update the those fields when the related field change

Comment: @UmairAbid So when I click on an autocomplete suggestion, I should add a hidden field containing the actual value that has to be passed? If so, then if I decide to erase my selection, type something new and select a new suggestion, I also have to add code to remove the invisible field created earlier right?

Comment: Yes, you will listen to change event of autocomplete field and set the hidden field when valid, you don't need to remove anything just process the hidden field while form submission and ignore autocomplete one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new hidden field which will hold the value that has to be passed and process it later.

```
c = document.createElement("DIV");
c.innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' value = '" + arr2[i] + "' name = 'newID'>";
this.parentNode.appendChild(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to have two separated arrays when their data related. I prefer to think on pairs. So, I used arr  (and countries in the  W3CSchools example) as JSON with:

```
var countries = {
  "Afghanistan": "af",
  "Algeria": "al",
  "República Argentina": "ar",
  "Belgium": "be",
  "Chile": "ch",
};
```

That's taking `arr` for keys and `arr2` for values.

`Object.keys(countries)` will be the array for the 2nd. parameter of autocomplete function. In the call:,

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), Object.keys(countries));
```

When submitting (`onSubmit`), you can assign the value to the hidden field, which must have a `name` attribute

```
<form [...] onsubmit="prepareData()" >
```

And then a function

```
function prepareData() {
  document.getElementById("myHiddenField").value = countries[document.getElementById("myInput").value];
}
```

I applied this to the W3CSchools example, here is the working example

```js
function getCountry() {
  // I just alert the value, this snippet does not go anywhere
  alert( countries[document.getElementById("myInput").value]);
}


function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an json (array) of possible autocompleted PAIR OF values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
      });
}


/*A JSON containing all the country names in the world:*/

var countries={"Afghanistan":"af","Algeria":"al","Argentina":"ar","Belgium":"be","Chile":"ch"};
/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), Object.keys(countries));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
}
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>     

<body>

<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="getCountry()">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```